# JBOSS Remote Backup of Application

Tags: java, jboss, jboss6.x, cargo

Does JBoss support downloading the deployed application remotely using Web console or Jmx operations? Like for websphere we have options for extracting the deployed application using admin console. I am looking for a Job do deploy the application to remotely and backup the existing deployed app. Cargo API also do not mention about the backup.

Somebody please point me to right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such feature is not supported in JBoss EAP 6/7 release.